malloc fails even with enough memory
I'm implementing a SkipList for academic purposes in C.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// ===============================================
// SkipList
// ===============================================
struct NO{
    int key;
    struct NO **next;
};

typedef struct SkipList SkipList;
struct SkipList{
    int levelMAX;
    float P;
    int level;
    struct NO *start;
};

struct NO* newNode(int key, int level){
    struct NO* node = malloc(sizeof(struct NO));
    if(node != NULL){
        node->key = key;
        node->next = malloc((level+1)* sizeof(struct NO*));
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<(level+1); i++)
            node->next[i] = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

SkipList* createSkipList(int levelMAX, float P){
    SkipList *sk = (SkipList*) malloc(sizeof(SkipList));
    if(sk != NULL){
        sk->levelMAX = levelMAX;
        sk->P = P;
        sk->level = 0;
        sk->start = newNode(-1, levelMAX);
    }
    return sk;
}

int drawlevel(SkipList *sk){
    float r = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    int level = 0;
    while(r < sk->P && level < sk->levelMAX){
        level++;
        r = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }
    return level;
}


int insertSkipList(SkipList *sk, int key){
    if(sk == NULL)
        return 0;

    int i;
    struct NO *atual = sk->start;
    struct NO **aux;
    aux = malloc((sk->levelMAX+1) * sizeof(struct NO*));
    for(i = 0; i <= sk->levelMAX; i++)
        aux[i] = NULL;

    for(i = sk->level; i >= 0; i--){
        while(atual->next[i] != NULL && atual->next[i]->key < key)
            atual = atual->next[i];
        aux[i] = atual;
    }

    atual = atual->next[0];

    if(atual == NULL || atual->key != key){
        int node_level = drawlevel(sk);
        struct NO* node = newNode(key, node_level);
        if(node == NULL){
            free(aux);
            return 0;
        }

        if(node_level > sk->level){
            for(i = sk->level+1; i <= node_level; i++)
                aux[i] = sk->start;

            sk->level = node_level;
        }

        for(i = 0; i <= node_level; i++){
            node->next[i] = aux[i]->next[i];
            aux[i]->next[i] = node;
        }

        free(aux);
        return 1;
    }

    free(aux);
    return 0;
}

void freeSkipList(SkipList* sk){
    if(sk == NULL)
        return;

    struct NO *no, *atual;
    atual = sk->start->next[0];
    while(atual != NULL){
        no = atual;
        atual = atual->next[0];
        free(no->next);
        free(no);
    }

    free(sk->start);
    free(sk);
}

// ===============================================

#define M 30
void Knuth_shuffle(int *array, int n){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j, tmp;
    for(i = n - 1; i > 0; i--){
        j = rand() % (i + 1);
        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
}

int* generateNumbers(int N){
    int *V = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    if(V == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i< N; i++)
        V[i] = i;

    Knuth_shuffle(V,N);
    return V;
}

void runSkipList(int *data, int N){
    int i, j, c = 0;
    int k = N / M;
    double ti;
    clock_t start, end;

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    SkipList *sk = createSkipList(25, 0.5);

    start = clock();
    for(i=0; i < M; i++){
        for(j=0; j < k; j++){
            insertSkipList(sk,data[c]);
            c++;
        }
        end = clock();
        ti = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("%d) %.10f sec\n",i+1,ti);
    }

    freeSkipList(sk);
}

int main(){
    int i, N = 60000000;
    int *data = generateNumbers(N);

    runSkipList(data, N);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}


After the insertion of 52,000,000 ints, malloc fails to allocate memory even though there is enough memory in RAM. I also checked the value of errno: 12 - Not enough memory is available for the attempted operator.
I'm using Win10 64bits, 16GB RAM, and Code::Blocks 16.01 (32bits).
Can someone help me?

Please try to reduce your code to a [mre]. If allocation is the issue, then most of the code around it is probably not relevenant. When you reduce the code you might also gain a better understanding of the problem.

Are you building a 32-bit or 64-bit executable? A 64-bit version will more memory per struct NO, but has access to more address space. A 32-bit process is limited to 2 GiB address space by default, although that can be increased to 4 GiB if compiled with -Wl,--large-address-aware.

I suspect that Windows, like Unix, has per-process limits of memory. So the machine might have lots of free memory, but that program used all that it is allowed to have. You'll have to research to discover how to manage it.

A 32 bits application cannot access to more than 3 GB, this application needs 5.3GB you must compile a 64bits application.

Call srand() once in the beginning of main() not in random code paths.  Prefer minimize scope of variables. Prefer initialized variables instead of separate assignment.  Prefer a  declaration per line.  You are wasting time if you don't check return values in this case malloc().  Don't cast the void * from malloc().  Prefer using a variable instead of type as argument to sizeof.  You have a memory leak easiest way to see it is to set N=1 so newNode() allocates node and node->next.  freeSkipList() frees node but doesn't free node->next.

The posted code runs for me on Linux unchanged so you should tag this with your platform.

Sorry, what is the use of struct NO **next; field in struct NO type?  Is the double pointer indeed required or is a mistake?
